# Picasso does not set image in landscape orientation

Tags: picasso

I want to set an image into an imageView. On portrait orientation it works properly. But when the device has landscape orientation it does not load the image.
The strange thing is, once I rotate it to portrait and back to landscape it shows the image properly.

```
private void setPhoto(File photoFile) {
    readyToDelete=false;
    try {
        Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .borderColor(Color.parseColor("#757575"))
                .borderWidthDp(3)
                .cornerRadiusDp(15)
                .oval(false)
                .build();


        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(photoFile)
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .transform(transformation)
                .into(imageView);

        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteImageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        addImageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        editScrollView.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are running out of memory while loading the image, when in landscape the image is bigger to fit the view.
Try this:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(image.getContext())
                .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Picasso error:"+exception.getCause().getMessage()+"\n"+uri);
                    }

                })
                .build();
```

then use the picasso instance:

```
picasso.load(photoFile)....
```

I recommend you to use a listener when loading, if you have an error, just load the image resizing it to lower resolution, half the screen size for example, let `screenSize` be the size in pixels of the device screen largest axis:

```
picasso.load(photoFile).....into(_imageView, new Callback.EmptyCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onError()
            {
                picasso.load(photoFile).resize(screenSize/2, screenSize/2).centerInside().transform(transformation).into(imageView);
            }
        });
```

anyway the log you get on your listener will give you the clue of what's happening